# Alternate to if statements for taking multiple form input values

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I have a HTML form for users to select country, region, bedroom number and price from.

```
<form action="" enctype="" method="POST">
<p>Property Search
<select name="search_country">
  <option value="">Select a country</option>
  <option value="uk">UK</option>
  <option value="france">France</option>
</select>
<select name="search_region">
  <option value="">Select a region</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
  <option value="birmingham">Birmingham</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="calais">Calais</option>
</select>
<select name="search_bedroomnumber">
  <option value="">Select number of bedrooms</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>   

<input type="submit" name="search_submit" value="Search" />
```

My current way of querying the database is an if statement for every variation of the selected form options like this:

```
if($_POST['search_country'] == "uk" and $_POST['search_region'] == "london" and $_POST['search_bedroomnumber'] == 4) {
$sqlcommand = "(SELECT * FROM properties 
WHERE country = 'uk' 
AND region = 'london' 
AND bedroomnumber = 4 
ORDER BY price ASC 
$properties = Properties::find_by_sql($sqlcommand);
};
```

With a lot of options, this would take a huge amount of if statements and i'm sure that there's a much more efficient way that i'm not seeing (very amateur coder here).

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The values in the `$_POST` are the same as in the database ?

Comment: you have a syntax error btw.

Comment: Plus, I think you're going about this the wrong way. Anyhow, you have answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Have to look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php, you can get all of the variables from $_POST into a variable after escaping and then use it within your query.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$country = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search_country']);
$region = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search_region']);
$bedroom = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search_bedroomnumber']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM properties 
WHERE country = '$country' 
AND region = '$region' 
AND bedroomnumber = $bedroom 
ORDER BY price ASC" ;
```

Then you can use this $sql.

Make sure you have other checks also in places like checking for empty input etc.

Answer (score 1):

PDO is the answer!

Combined with `filter_input` for maximum effect

Gather all your parameters: (add sanitization)

```
$country = isset($_POST['country']) ? $_POST['country'] : 'uk';
...
```

Write your query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM properties 
WHERE country = :country 
AND region = :region 
AND bedroomnumber = :bedroomnumber 
ORDER BY price ASC';
```

Prepare your query

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

Bind the parameters:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':country', $country);
...
```

Execute and fetch:

```
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if($_POST['search_country'] && $_POST['search_region'] && $_POST['search_bedroomnumber']) {

    $country = $_POST['search_country'];
    $region = $_POST['search_region'];
    $bedroomNo = $_POST['search_bedroomnumber'];

    $sqlcommand = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE country = '$country' AND region = '$region' AND bedroomnumber = $bedroomNo ORDER BY price ASC ";
    $properties = Properties::find_by_sql($sqlcommand);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need those that IF at all. Just assign all your expected GET or POST values to a variable and put those variables into your SQL code after escaping them.